# java repeat one part of the output

Tags: java, eclipse, io, filereader, java-io

I have Java assignment , and this is the explanation of the
In your program create three classes: `InputHandler`, `OutputHandler` and Student classes. The `InputHandler` class handles the reading of information from the input file. It also contains an array of Student objects to store the information in it. The `OutputHandler` class takes the array of students provided through a method in the `InputHandler` class. Then, It should print the whole record of each student along with the calculated average in the ‘results.txt’ file. It also should calculate and print the standard deviation. Finally, the Student class, contains the fields to store the information of the student. It also has a method called getQuizAverage() which calculates and returns the average of the quizzes for that particular student which is used by the OutputHandler to print it in the result file.

**Input file**

input.txt:

99091;Mohammed;7;5.5;7;8;9

99092;Khalid;7;5.5;7;8;8

99093;Ali;7;5.5;7;8;9

99094;Ahmad;7;5.5;7;8;9

**Output.txt**

99091   Mohammed    7         5.5        7        8       9       7.3

99092   Khalid      7         5.5        7        8       8       7.1

99093   Ali         7         5.5        7        8       9       7.3

99094   Ahmad       7         5.5        7        8       9       7.3

**The problem that I get only one repeated output**

99094   Ahmad       7         5.5        7        8       9       7.3

99094   Ahmad       7         5.5        7        8       9       7.3

99094   Ahmad       7         5.5        7        8       9       7.3

99094   Ahmad       7         5.5        7        8       9       7.3

my classes I have 4 classes , Student , inputhandler , outputhandler , main

```
public class Student {

    public String Name;
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public double getQuiz1() {
        return quiz1;
    }

    public void setQuiz1(double quiz1) {
        this.quiz1 = quiz1;
    }
    public double getQuiz2() {
        return quiz2;
    }
    public void setQuiz2(double quiz2) {
        this.quiz2 = quiz2;
    }

    public double getQuiz3() {
        return quiz3;
    }

    public void setQuiz3(double quiz3) {
        this.quiz3 = quiz3;
    }

    public double getQuiz4() {
        return quiz4;
    }

    public void setQuiz4(double quiz4) {
        this.quiz4 = quiz4;
    }

    public double getQuiz5() {
        return quiz5;
    }

    public void setQuiz5(double quiz5) {
        this.quiz5 = quiz5;
    }

    public double getAvgQuiz() {
        return avgQuiz;
    }

    public void setAvgQuiz(double avgQuiz) {
        this.avgQuiz = avgQuiz;
    }

    public  String ID;
    public double quiz1;
    public double quiz2;
    public double quiz3;
    public double quiz4;
    public double quiz5;

    public double avgQuiz;

    public double getQuizAverage()
    {
       return ((quiz1+quiz2+quiz3+quiz4+quiz5)/5);
    }

    public Student() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

InputHandler

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class InputHandler {

    Student[] myStudent = new Student[4];

    public InputHandler(String fileName) {
        this.inputData(fileName);
    }

    private void inputData(String fileName) {

        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line;


            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
            String[] parts = line.split(";");


                for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                {

                    myStudent[i] = new Student();
                    myStudent[i].setID(parts[0]);
                    myStudent[i].setName(parts[1]);
                    myStudent[i].setQuiz1(Double.parseDouble(parts[2]));
                    myStudent[i].setQuiz2(Double.parseDouble(parts[3]));
                    myStudent[i].setQuiz3(Double.parseDouble(parts[4]));
                    myStudent[i].setQuiz4(Double.parseDouble(parts[5]));
                    myStudent[i].setQuiz5(Double.parseDouble(parts[6]));
                }     

        }


            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Student [] getStudents() {
        return myStudent;
    }
}
```

OutputHandler

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

public class OutputHandler {

    Student[] myStudent;

    public OutputHandler(Student[] stds) {

        myStudent = stds;
    }

    void writeData() throws IOException {
        FileWriter writt = new FileWriter("output.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            writt.write(myStudent[i].ID + '\t' + myStudent[i].Name + '\t'
                    + '\t' + myStudent[i].quiz1 + '\t' + myStudent[i].quiz2
                    + '\t' + myStudent[i].quiz3 + '\t' + myStudent[i].quiz4
                    + '\t' + myStudent[i].quiz5 + '\t'+"  "+myStudent[i].getQuizAverage());
            writt.write('\n');

        }

        writt.close();

    }
}
```

Main function

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputHandler ih=new InputHandler("input.txt");
        OutputHandler output1 = new OutputHandler(ih.getStudents());
        output1.writeData();    

    }

}
```

Comment: Please Post Short Code, It's like I am reading a story ! Just look at [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please refer to [ask] - in it's current state, it is unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: i but the problem in a Bold fonts , I cant say a little about the problem because always people here ask us to give a full description to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove a for loop inside InputHandler class inputData method. Because you read line by line student information. Looping again is wrong. It should be like this

```
private void inputData(String fileName) {

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;

        int studentIndex = 0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
           String[] parts = line.split(";");
           myStudent[studentIndex] = new Student();
           myStudent[studentIndex].setID(parts[0]);
           myStudent[studentIndex].setName(parts[1]);
           myStudent[studentIndex].setQuiz1(Double.parseDouble(parts[2]));
           myStudent[studentIndex].setQuiz2(Double.parseDouble(parts[3]));
           myStudent[studentIndex].setQuiz3(Double.parseDouble(parts[4]));
           myStudent[studentIndex].setQuiz4(Double.parseDouble(parts[5]));
           myStudent[studentIndex].setQuiz5(Double.parseDouble(parts[6]));
           studentIndex++;

    }
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: but if i don't have a loop how it will read all the information for other students

Comment: you're using a `while()` to loop through the lines

Comment: like @TeneCursum specified you are already reading student information line by line. Reading line means that looping.

Answer (score 0):

In input header you are trying to link parts of same line to all objects. Needs to put line in for loop too.

Comment: can you give me a short code so i can understand what do you mean